# Eclipse 4.5.1 and SonarQube Issue Tracker View

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, issue-tracking, sonarlint

actually I am trying to setup **SonarQube** for my PHP-Project.

In my Eclipse Installation I'm trying to use the **"SonarQube Issue Editor"** which is shown here:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/download/attachments/6948813/sonarqube-eclipse-overview.png?version=1&modificationDate=1383220387000&api=v2&effects=drop-shadow

But I can't find this view, where you can directly edit the issue.

Everything other works well, i see the **Issues-Tab** and also the **Rule Description**.

Also tried **SonarLint** but there is the same like in SonarQube-Plugin.

Has anyone else have this problem, or a solution for it?

Is there maybe an other solution to edit the issues in eclipse, which are created by SonarQube?

I don't find anything else in the forum or on Google....
I Just don't get it.. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from SonarLint developer:

SonarLint does not support associating a project with a particular SonarQube server, so there is no such editing possible at the moment. We plan to keep adding features to SonarLint so stay tuned!